# Dropdown Live search in Bulma CSS framework

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bulma, bootstrap-select

Is there any way i can also perform Live search in Drop-down while using the [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) CSS framework.

As in Bootstrap there is a jquery plugin named as [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select) which allows us to perform live search in drop-down. 
When I tried to use this plugin with bulma the whole layout scattered

I am beginner of Bulma. a little Help would be grateful

Comment: Hi [Umer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5450900/umer),
aren't you satisfied with my answer?
Have you checked the provided fiddle?
What's the problem with it?
Let us know how we can help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use *selectize*:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/css/selectize.min.css
To use the live search just use:

```
$(function() {
  $('select').selectize();
});
```

Here is [a working fiddle](https://codepen.io/meziano/pen/wvaJLEo)